# Вычисление выражения в строке

Tags: php

```
$stroka = "10+2";
$rezultat = $stroka;
print $rezultat;
```

Как сделать так чтобы переменная `$rezultat` равнялась результату выражения, записанного в `$stroka`? (в выражении могут быть операции `+-*/()`)

Comment: Нужно ли поддерживать скобки, умножение, деление, возведение в степень, числа с плавающей строчкой, переменные, функции и т.д.? Вот аналогичный вопрос для Питона: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Comment: Уточните цель, которую вы хотите достичь. В текущей формулировке вопроса правильным ответом будет `$rezultat = 12;`

Comment: В строке будут уравнения, +, - , / , * , ()  вот что мне понадобится

Comment: 1. Это лучше дописать в вопрос 2. Постарайтесь формулировать более полно вопросы. Все ответы, которые вам уже дали, в свете нового комментария, никуда не годятся. Почитайте http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709

Comment: Уравнения или арифметические выражения (это разные вещи)? Числа только целые?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кину еще один вариант:

```
// Исключения для парсера выражений
class AriphmeticException extends Exception {
    function __construct($msg, $code) {
        return parent::__construct($msg, $code);
    }
    function __toString() {
        return get_class($this) . '(' 
            . $this->code . '): ' 
            . $this->message;
    }
}

// Собственно сам вычислитель выражений
function calculate($statement) {
    if (!is_string($statement)) {
        throw new AriphmeticException('Wrong type', 1);
    }
    $calcQueue = array();
    $operStack = array();
    $operPriority = array(
        '(' => 0,
        ')' => 0,
        '+' => 1,
        '-' => 1,
        '*' => 2,
        '/' => 2,
    );
    $token = '';
    foreach (str_split($statement) as $char) {
        // Если цифра, то собираем из цифр число
        if ($char >= '0' && $char <= '9') {
            $token .= $char;
        } else {
            // Если число накопилось, сохраняем в очереди вычисления
            if (strlen($token)) {
                array_push($calcQueue, $token);
                $token = '';
            }
            // Если найденный символ - операция (он есть в списке приоритетов)
            if (isset($operPriority[$char])) {
                if (')' == $char) {
                    // Если символ - закрывающая скобка, переносим операции из стека в очередь вычисления пока не встретим открывающую скобку
                    while (!empty($operStack)) {
                        $oper = array_pop($operStack);
                        if ('(' == $oper) {
                            break;
                        }
                        array_push($calcQueue, $oper);
                    }
                    if ('(' != $oper) {
                        // Упс! А открывающей-то не было. Сильно ругаемся (18+)
                        throw new AriphmeticException('Unexpected ")"', 2);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Встретили операцию кроме скобки. Переносим операции с меньшим приоритетом в очередь вычисления
                    while (!empty($operStack) && '(' != $char) {
                        $oper = array_pop($operStack);
                        if ($operPriority[$char] > $operPriority[$oper]) {
                            array_push($operStack, $oper);
                            break;
                        }
                        if ('(' != $oper) {
                            array_push($calcQueue, $oper);
                        }
                    }
                    // Кладем операцию на стек операций
                    array_push($operStack, $char);
                }
            } elseif (strpos(' ', $char) !== FALSE) {
                // Игнорируем пробелы (можно добавить что еще игнорируем)
            } else {
                // Встретили что-то непонятное (мы так не договаривались). Опять ругаемся
                throw new AriphmeticException('Unexpected symbol "' . $char . '"', 3);
            }
        }

    }
    // Вроде все разобрали, но если остались циферки добавляем их в очередь вычисления
    if (strlen($token)) {
        array_push($calcQueue, $token);
        $token = '';
    }
    // ... и оставшиеся в стеке операции
    if (!empty($operStack)) {
        while ($oper = array_pop($operStack)) {
            if ('(' == $oper) {
                // ... кроме открывающих скобок. Это верный признак отсутствующей закрывающей
                throw new AriphmeticException('Unexpected "("', 4);
            }
            array_push($calcQueue, $oper);
        }
    }
    $calcStack = array();
    // Теперь вычисляем все то, что напарсили
    // Тут ошибки не ловил, но они могут быть (это домашнее задание)
    foreach ($calcQueue as $token) {
        switch ($token) {
        case '+':
            $arg2 = array_pop($calcStack);
            $arg1 = array_pop($calcStack);
            array_push($calcStack, $arg1 + $arg2);
            break;
        case '-':
            $arg2 = array_pop($calcStack);
            $arg1 = array_pop($calcStack);
            array_push($calcStack, $arg1 - $arg2);
            break;
        case '*':
            $arg2 = array_pop($calcStack);
            $arg1 = array_pop($calcStack);
            array_push($calcStack, $arg1 * $arg2);
            break;
        case '/':
            $arg2 = array_pop($calcStack);
            $arg1 = array_pop($calcStack);
            array_push($calcStack, $arg1 / $arg2);
            break;
        default:
            array_push($calcStack, $token);
        }
    }
    return array_pop($calcStack);
}
```

По заданной теме можно почитать:

1. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C);
2. [статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/100869/);
3. [английский SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17645253/3349900) (это если очень хочется реализовать решение задачи через `eval()`)

Answer (score 3):

Мой вариант небольшой, может и костыль, но более универсальный

```
$str = "100/10*2+10";
$number = array();

$z = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < iconv_strlen($str); $i++){
    if (is_numeric($str[$i])){
        $number[$z] .= $str[$i];
    } else {
        $z++;
        $number[$z] = $str[$i];
        $z++;
    }
};

for ($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i++){
    $number[$i] = (int) $number[$i];
    $i++;
    $number[$i] = (string) $number[$i];
}

$res = $number[0];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i++){
    if ($number[$i+1] === '+') {
        $res += $number[$i+2];
    }elseif($number[$i+1] === '-'){
        $res -= $number[$i+2];
    }elseif($number[$i+1] === '*'){
        $res *= $number[$i+2];
    }elseif($number[$i+1] === '/'){
        $res /= $number[$i+2];
    }
    $i++;
}

echo $res;
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но `preg_split` тут избыточен явно. К символам строки есть индексный доступ не отличающийся от доступа к элементам массива. Кроме того не реализована приоритезация операций.

Comment: @Владимир Рекомендую развить именно направление данное в этом ответе (может даже автор ответа его доработает)

Comment: @tutankhamun просто хочу для себя придумать алгоритм именно с приоритезацией. В голову пришла лишь одна мысль, но все очень закручено выходит.
Как я представляю, после того как создали окончательно массив $number, нужно будет по нему проходиться от начала и до конца, что бы выявить где есть знаки умножения и деления. Запомнить эти индексы и потом уже выполнить операции умножения и деления с удаление этих элементов массива. А потом уже выполнить все остальные операции. Что не правильно в моем алгоритме?

Comment: @neek а если так `$str = "100 / 10 * (2 + 10)"` ? Появились пробелы и группировка выражений

Comment: Про правильный алгоритм читайте [Обратная польская запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_польская_запись)

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой **вариант**:

```
$stroka = "10+2";
$sum = 0;
$broken_str = explode('+',$stroka);
//Можем сделать раширенную функциональность для многих '+'-иков
foreach($broken_str as $key=>$value)
{
  //используем (int) для переобразовании строки на число
  $sum += (int)$value;
}
print($sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё один **вариант решения**.

```
$stroka = "10+2";
$rezultat=eval("return $stroka;");
echo $rezultat;
```

Единственное "но". **Использование eval без серьёзной необходимости и фильтрации входных данных крайне не рекомендуется.**

Comment: Вот этот вариант без тщательной фильтрации входных данных нельзя даже показывать